# Trying to receive information from database: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable"

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I receive my information from db into `DataTable`?

I have an error on `DataTable`: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable"

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{  
    private DataTable dataTable;
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string query = "select * from tbl_news";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dataTable);
        conn.Close();
        da.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: it,s just my cod and i first time use that this query

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you to instantiate the `DataTable` first.

You can do this when you first define it, or in the method itself... just make it is, before you try to fill it.

```
dataTable = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dataTable);
```

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't say anything about what it does if the `DataTable` is `null`. It'd be nice if it checked for `null` and instantiated it before trying to fill it.

I dug into the assembly, and there's definitely code in there that checks for `null`, and throws an `ArgumentNullException` if it is. The code is spread across several methods, but it boils down to:

```
if (dataTables == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("dataTable");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception message:

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: dataTable"

tells you that the `DataTable` is `null` and must not be `null`. You can't fill a table that doesn't exist. It Is an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is typically thrown from a method to ensure that a required passed argument is not `null`.

To fix it you just have to initialize the table.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_news", conn))
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        // no need to open the connection with DataAdapter.Fill
        da.Fill(dataTable);
    } // no need to close the connection with using-statement anyway

    // do something with the table here, f.e. assign it as datasource 
    // for a webdatabound control like GridView
    // ...
}
```

The documentation does not mention this exception explicitly, you can  find it [in the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataAdapter.cs,edc41c0b93012bd4,references).

Why you don't need to open/close connections with [`Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The connection object associated with the SELECT statement must be
>   valid, but it does not need to be open. If the connection is closed
>   before Fill is called, it is opened to retrieve data, then closed. If
>   the connection is open before Fill is called, it remains open.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize data table like this

```
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
```

Then fill it

```
    da.fill(dataTable);
```